# What is the name of function, which codomain is a given set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a special short term for any function

$F$

from the family of functions

$F(A)$

for the given set

$A$

so that $A$ is the codomain of any function $F \in F(A)$?

For example, suppose we have a set of numbers $A = [-1,+1]$ and the function of $\sin(x)$ where $x \in R$. What is $\sin$ for $A$?

Comment: Do you mean image rather than codomain? The image is a subset of the codomain but not necessarily the whole thing.

Comment: I mean codomain. What is function for it's codomain? Builder? Supporter? Generator? Definer? Painter? Something like this.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "function with codomain $A$"; whereas a given function has a unique codomain, a given set may be the codomain of many functions.

Comment: You really need to properly define $\sin$ before you can say what its codomain is. Some would take $\sin\colon\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$ to be *the* function $\sin$ while others would take $\sin\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. These functions have different codomains.

Comment: Ok, there is probably no special term. Also now agree that an "image" is also suitable... So my question was "what is the function to it's image", like "- who is the person to his son?" "- a father"...

Comment: @CliveNewstead agree, but I was looking special should term, not manyword phrase...

Comment: @Dims: What makes you think such a word exists? What use would it have?